# Upgrade Evaluation Version of SQL Server to Licence Version

Tags: sql-server-2008

We downloaded SQL Server 2008 R2 enterprise edition from Microsoft site which were 180 days trial version. Now trial period has been expired and we want to convert it into license version. For that I read somewhere that we just need to click on upgrade version and need to enter product key. Once we enter it,all is set. But our problem is I asked to Admin team of my company and they told that for our corporate license we don't have product key but we have license version setup. Now I don't know how can I convert my evaluation version to license version without entering product key.

Please help me. Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Mohit Leekha

Comment: I would let your Admin team handle this problem. They should be able to call Microsoft for assistance.  Worst case you backup your databases and reinstall everything from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally its done.

The SQL server setup itself provides me an option for upgradation where i just browsed the previous instance of my evaluation version SQL server.

Thanks and regards